# Restfb Get Event, Location and Venue is null

Tags: java, restfb

When I try to get a specific event using RestFb with the following code:

```
    Event event = facebookClient.fetObject(eventId, Event.class);
```

I am able to get the event content, time, etc. However, the location and venue fields are null even though on the specific event does have a location.

Comment: Can you provide an example event id or the json facebook returns?

Comment: @Norbert Event id: 963563046988382

Comment: which Graph API version do you use? Venue and location is deprecated with API 2.3, so you won't get these fields

Comment: @Norbert Using 2.3. So there is a "place" field that you have to put in manually to get the desired result. The place field however does not work in restfb.

Comment: not in the 1.10.1. With 1.11.0 this is possible and the new version will be released soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use RestFB 1.11.0. The Event-type in that version supports the new place field. venue and location is deprecated with Graph API 2.3.